# Retrieve custom field from Contact Form 7

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields, plugin-contact-form-7

This is the scenario: I have a lot of posts (Custom Post Types) and in each one I have the same CF7. When the user submits the form, I'd like to have, in the email that will be sent, a field from my Custom Post showing in the email body. I'm using Advanced Custom Fields to generate this field.
I read a lot about this, and maybe I'm close to the solution, but there is a mess in my mind and I'm pretty stuck. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Example: 
 - Custom Post Type: Book
 - CF7: Ask info about this book

In the email, I want to have:
"Hi! You asked for info about *book_title_here*"

Where "book_title_here" is an advanced custom field.